# Google Cloud Stackdriver Monitor Compute Engine Disk Usage

Tags: cloud, google-compute-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-platform

I have Google compute engine instances already up and running since recently.

I have explored Google Cloud stackdriver for monitoring CPU Usage etc.

I have installed Stackdriver agent on to one of the Compute Engine instance for testing. I have explored creating new chart on dashboard, tried with various metrics.

But I could not find any metrics that can show **disk usage** of my instance.

Yes there is list of plugins supported by Stackdriver agent to pump custom metrics but I could not find any specific metric that measure the instance disk usage.

Please give me a pointer.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Volume usage is added as a metrics after you install the standard agent (no additional plugins are needed). But you need to search for the word `volume` not `disk` to find this metric when adding it to a chart.
[image]

After you install the agent for the first time it can take a few minutes before the new metrics shows up.

FYI : the list of plugins https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/.  Mostly they add metrics for web-servers or database servers.  And you can add custom metrics : https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/

Cheers!

Comment: cool! I was impatient to see those agent-based metrics get listed. I took quite some times. Now it is listed with a whole lot of useful metrics. thanks @eSniff for help

Comment: I am unable to do so in Stackdriver for GKE Compute Engine Instances. Do I need to install agents  ?? or they are installed by default by GKE??

Comment: @gaurav9 you have to install the agent on your VMs.

Comment: The metric name changed to "Disk Utilization"

Answer (score 2):

The UI changed slightly.

1. Look for Operations -> Monitoring -> Metrics Explorer.
2. Resource type: VM Instance
3. Metric: Disk utilization (agent.googleapis.com/disk/percent_used)
4. To filter by instance name (instead of numeric instance id) use: 'system metadata label -> name'

[image]