# Alert to detect the available space on the hard drive

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I would like to know if it is possible to create an alert in a google cloud platform instance, to identify that a hard drive of an instance is 90% busy, for example, and that this sends a notification to some user.

I await your response, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Stackdrive to setup alerts and have an email sent.

However, disk percentage busy is not an available metric. You can chose from `Disk Read I/O` and `Disk Write I/O` bytes per second and set a threshold for the metric.

- Go to the Google Console Stackdriver section. Click on Monitoring.
- Select Alerting -> Create Policy in the left panel.
- Create your alerting policy based upon Conditions and Notifications

You can create custom metrics. This link describes how.

[Creating Custom Metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics)

Comment: So, there is no way to know when a hard drive is running out of space automatically and notify an email?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: You can create custom metrics to support date points that are not built into Stackdriver.

Comment: As 'John' explained, creating custom metrics can help you in this matter. Also, I invite you to have a look at this [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37716936/google-cloud-stackdriver-monitor-compute-engine-disk-usage).